# How to setup Keras Autoencoder and reshape() to process 224 x 224 jpg images using ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to apply a [Tensorflow Keras autoencoder implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder) to my own dataset of 224 x 224 images belonging to 40 classes, which I have setup like: 
[image]

I'm using ImageDataGenerator to create train, validation, and test sets; training set size is 13,988; test & validation sizes are both 3,000.

But no matter how I set these parameters I get errors like:

> InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[3], expected a dimension of 1, got 3

Or mismatched shapes errors.

I think I am not setting up my autoencoder correctly. Can someone please spot the problem and tell me how  I can fix my code to get this working?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import os

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

latent_dim =  64

class Autoencoder(Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim   
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
    ])
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(50176, activation='sigmoid'),
      layers.Reshape((224, 224))
    ])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded
  
autoencoder = Autoencoder(latent_dim) 

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.MeanSquaredError())

train_datagen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'ae_data/train',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='input',
    color_mode='rgb')

validation_datagen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'ae_data/validation',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='input',
    color_mode='rgb')

test_datagen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'ae_data/test',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='input',
    color_mode='rgb')



autoencoder.fit(train_datagen, steps_per_epoch=218, validation_data=test_datagen, epochs=1,
               shuffle=False, validation_steps=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial uses fashion MNIST grayscale images. You might be using rgb images.

Since, the error states that it can't squeeze 3 values into 1, your image size should be 224 x 224 x 3. Third dimension denotes 3 values for rgb.

Now, if colour is not important, you can preprocess your images to grayscale first.